# Can anybody help me identify this font used for this LINE sticker?

Tags: font-identification, japanese

I want to ask what font is used in this photo. I've tried using various font finding services but it would seem that the texts being Japanese has made it very difficult to correctly determine it.

If this is a custom font, do you guys know if there are any similar fonts like this ? Thanks

[image]

Comment: What is a "line sticker"?  Looks like this could be a regular font, but with some [stroke layer styles applied](https://imgur.com/2qwaMTx), perhaps using software such as Photoshop. I've no idea which particular base font was used as I don't speak/write Japanese. Sorry.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you for responding. Yeah, LINE is a messaging app used a lot in Japan, and the stickers are pretty much message stickers that people used on Snapchat, Messenger and whatnot.